# Do/make a hairstyle

Tags: word-usage, light-verbs

Is it natural to say:

> She made a hairstyle.
>
> She did a hairstyle.

What sounds natural: make/do?

Comment: Neither... are you describing someone doing something with their own hair or someone else’s (is she a professional hairstylist)?

Comment: You *have* a *hairstyle*, but you *do* your *hair* (or someone else’s hair).

Comment: Yes , she "did someone's hair". Can't this variation be used as well:  "I'll make your hairstyle. "?

Comment: You can’t use “make” like that, if the object is just “hairstyle”. Sentences like “I’ll make your hairstyle fun” or “I’ll make your hairstyle better” are ok, because here “make (adj)” means “to cause to be (adj)”, and there isn’t a restriction on what nouns can be the object of this type of phrase. But “make” meaning “create” isn’t used with the object “hairstyle” (at least in my experience as an American English speaker).

Comment: @Mixolydian   So for another sentence can it be : I'll do your makeup. (And can it be: "I'm doing makeup" for myself?)

Comment: You normally specify a personal possessive pronoun when describing grooming; that’s why I originally asked if you were talking about her own hair or someone else’s hair. “I’m doing my makeup” is what you’d say when you’re doing your own makeup.

Comment: And can it be "I'll do your face"? @Mixolydian.  And why did medicine-man used it(even though with a definite article), because you said it's not used....

Comment: Yes- “I’ll do your face” is informal but sounds fine to me. It’s possible @medicine_man speaks a dialect of English that is different from mine where “make X’s hairstyle” sounds more natural. I do agree with m_m that using a non-personal pronoun (a, the) with “hairstyle” is appropriate for a generic hairstyle that many people might have. E.g. “I’m the inventor of *a* hairstyle that many celebrities are wearing.”

Comment: Also acceptable: "She styled someone's hair."

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples are correct.

---

These are natural (depending on how you finish the question):

> 1. She has a hairstyle ...

or:

> 2. Her hairstyle is ...

---

Also:

> 3. She did her hair.
> 4. She had a haircut.

mean that she had some changes to her hair.

Answer (score 0):

> She made a hairstyle.
>
> She did a hairstyle.

Both of these sentences could be perceived as awkward. Referring to a ***hairstyle*** usually is possessive of someone else, so personal pronouns would sound better here. The only way it would sound better to use a definite article (a, an, and the) would be if she made a **generic** hairstyle that many people would use/wear.

> She made ***her*** hairstyle.
>
> She made ***Bob's*** hairstyle.
>
> She made ***their*** hairstyles.
>
> She did ***my*** hairstyle.
>
> She made ***a*** hairstyle for the young girls.

Also, the usage of the word ***do*** in the second example is more of an English Language idiom, similar to that of the phrases ***break a leg*** or ***under the weather***. [Here](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-idioms/) is a common list of other English idioms.

Comment: Mixolydian says it can't be used... So I'm confused @medicine_man

Comment: Mixolydian views make as in not to create. If you view make similarly to creating (create a hairstyle), then this is acceptable. The issue here is with the word make, because it can be an adjective and a verb.

Comment: So it can be used? (I just read your comment) for "doing someone's hair?

Comment: Yes, you can use do and make as verbs in these sentences. It's more about the adjectives in this example.

Comment: @medicine_man Please don't use `preformatted text` for emphasis. See [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4644/what-is-a-preformatted-text-for).

Comment: @Davo. Please understand this is a suggestion, and not a requirement. But because you asked, I will change my original post. Next time, please do not ask imperatively.